# How to respond to a customer's demand for payment extension?

Tags: salary, billing

I have a client who wants to purchase an artwork. After three weeks of questioning about my artwork finally he is convinced to buy it. I have offered him discount after his multiple request and 15 days of payment time in invoice. Now he is asking for payment extension. I think that he might ask for extension again! I'm actually tired of him because he is not paying and wasting my time. How to deal with it? Your expert opinions are appreciated.

I have not mentioned late fee or due date interest fee in the invoice.

Comment: You're the seller, give him a deadline. Buyer doesn't respect that deadline; move on to more serious buyers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a workplace issue, it's a business issue.

Comment: Who has the art, you or the buyer?

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-to-respond-to-a-customers-demand-for-payment-extension

Comment: The question is out of scope here, but the basic advice is simple: ***Stick up for yourself.*** If he doesn't have the art yet tell him that you have been more than generous in your dealing with him, and are sorry to hear that the transaction will not be going ahead. Then put the piece back on the market. If he _does_ have the piece then you're basically screwed, and need to possibly contact a lawyer. You might first try a passive aggressive approach such as: "If you are unable to meet the payment deadline we would be more than happy to accept the return of the artwork". See how he responds.

Comment: Agree, never give out the goods before getting paid for them.

Comment: I am an graphic designer, i do freelance graphic design, He likes one of my artworks so he is interested in purchasing the copyrights! @Myles

Comment: Then come up with a price, and when he pays, he gets the artwork and the copyright. And if he doesn't pay, he gets neither.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm actually tired of him because he is not paying and wasting my
>   time. How to deal with it?

Tell him that you apparently cannot make him happy and that he should probably look for his art elsewhere.

Then just move on.

Comment: He is paying a good price, i actually want to do business with the client but i do not know how to respond to his payment extension request. Thanks for you input!

Comment: He's not actually paying you a good price, because he doesn't have the money to pay you.

Comment: @AmirDe - I thought you said he was not paying? Maybe you mean that he promises to pay a good price? Promises are cheap.

Comment: I think i should ask him to pay a non-refundable payment (maybe 10% of the agreed price) to hold the item for 30 days? What do you think ? @WorkerDrone